# Create a semi circle with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I want to create a perfect semi circle at the bottom of my view and now I'm getting  just an arc in the top of a rectangle (see attached picture). This is the code I'm using is the following where circularRect is origin = (x = 128, y = 514), size = (width = 64, height = 54)

```
    CGFloat arcHeight = 60.0;
    CGRect arcRect = CGRectMake(circularRect.origin.x, circularRect.origin.y + circularRect.size.height - arcHeight, circularRect.size.width, arcHeight);

    CGFloat arcRadius = 60;
    CGPoint arcCenter = CGPointMake(arcRect.origin.x + arcRect.size.width/2, arcRect.origin.y + arcRadius);

    CGFloat angle = acos(arcRect.size.width / (2*arcRadius));
    CGFloat startAngle = 270 * M_PI/180 + angle;
    CGFloat endAngle = 90 * M_PI/180 - angle;

    CGContextAddArc(context, arcCenter.x, arcCenter.y, arcHeight, startAngle, endAngle, 1);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextClearRect(context, arcRect);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect( context, arcRect);
```

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The radius you're supplying to the arc function is too large.  Your rectangle width being 64, you can only fit a circle that has a radius of 32 or less in it.